# Use lombok to generate constructor that param takes in additional params

Tags: java, lombok

I am refactoring some legacy code, trying to use Lombok to make it a bit cleaner.

Right now the constructor of my class is defined as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final YourClass yourClass;

    public MyClass(final A a, final B b) {
        yourClass = new YourClass(a, b);
    } 
}
```

How do I use Lombok to make this happen?

Comment: This doesn't look like boilerplate from hell, why refractor this? I'm not aware of any lombok annotation fixing this problem though.

Comment: @YassinHajaj this is way simplified comparing to what I m having. Just want to know if this can be done or not.

Comment: That is not possible with Lombok.

Comment: @Builder on both `MyClass` and `YourClass` might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have additional parameters of an arbitrary type, there is no way for Lombok (or any other annotation processing mechanism) to determine how you want your constructor to look like and behave.

You will have to define your own constructor or a static factory method. Or use the builder pattern.